# The property 'length' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'. Try making the access conditional (using '?.') or adding a

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test

[image: when I Try To Access Data from API I got this Error help me.]

when I Try To Access Data from API I got this Error help me.

Comment: Have you tried doing what the error suggests? How would you access data on a null object? Should you perhaps check whether or not the object you are accessing is in fact not null before you access it?

Comment: no what is that actually error saying sir?

Comment: What the error is saying is that the data from the request may be null. What null means is that the object has no values in it, or more specifically that there is nothing there at all. If you understand pointers this should make sense, but if not then simply think of null as being an absence of data. If you are trying to gain insight into an absence of data, that doesn't really make sense semantically. If I give you a bag with nothing in it and ask you for a ball from that bag, what should you do for it. You must check whether it is null or analogously that the bag is empty before asking

Comment: so now what is the solution for this?

Comment: You appear to already be checking if the data is null, so you can just put an `!` before the `[index]`

Answer (score 1):

fix it by putting 'AsyncSnapshot' before snapshot in the builder parameter;

```dart
builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot)
```

Answer (score 0):

change SDK 2.12.0 to SDK 2.7.0

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this might work

Comment: Reasoning would be important because you are suggesting downgrading.